# Dsift (vl_feat) and Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

I have a (naïve probably) question, I just wanted to clarify this part. So, when I take a `dsift` on one image I generally get an `128xn matrix`. Thing is, that n value, is not always the same across different images. Say image 1 gets an `128x10 matrix`, while image 2 gets a `128x18 matrix`. I am not quite sure why is this happening.

I think that each column of 128dimension represents a single image feature or a single patch detected from the image. So in the case of 128x18, we have extracted 18 patches and described them with 128 values each. If this is correct, why cant we have a fixed numbers of patches per image, say 20 patches, so every time our matrixes would be 128x20.

Cheers!

Comment: If you had added code to your question I wouldn't have wasted my time looking at the wrong thing.  You meant sift, not dsift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the number of reliable features that are detected per image change.  Just because you detect 10 features in one image does **not** mean that you will be able to detect the same number of features in the other image.  What **does matter** is how close one feature from one image matches with another.

What you can do (if you like) is extract the, say, 10 **most reliable** features that are matched the best between the two images, if you want to have something constant.  Choose a number that is less than or equal to the minimum of the number of patches detected between the two.  For example, supposing you detect 50 features in one image, and 35 features in another image.  After, when you try and match the features together, this results in... say... 20 best matched points.  You can choose the best 10, or 15, or even all of the points (20) and proceed from there.

I'm going to show you some example code to illustrate my point above, but bear in mind that I will be using `vl_sift` and not `vl_dsift`.  The reason why is because I want to show you visual results with minimal pre- and post-processing.  Should you choose to use `vl_dsift`, you'll need to do a bit of work before and after you compute the features by `dsift` if you want to visualize the same results.  If you want to see the code to do that, you can check out the `vl_dsift` help page here: http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html.  Either way, the idea about choosing the most reliable features applies to both `sift` and `dsift`.

For example, supposing that `Ia` and `Ib` are `uint8` grayscale images of the same object or scene.  You can first detect features via SIFT, then match the keypoints.

```
[fa, da] = vl_sift(im2single(Ia));
[fb, db] = vl_sift(im2single(Ib));
[matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(da, db);
```

`matches` contains a `2 x N` matrix, where the first row and second row of each column denotes which feature index in the first image (first row) matched best with the second image (second row).

Once you do this, sort the scores in **ascending** order.  Lower scores mean better matches as the default matching method between two features is the Euclidean / L<sub>2</sub> norm.  As such:

```
numBestPoints = 10;
[~,indices] = sort(scores);

%// Get the numBestPoints best matched features
bestMatches = matches(:,indices(1:numBestPoints));
```

This should then return the 10 best matches between the two images.  FWIW, your understanding about how the features are represented in `vl_feat` is spot on.  These are stored in `da` and `db`.  Each column represents a descriptor of a particular patch in the image, and it is a histogram of 128 entries, so there are 128 rows per feature.

Now, as an added bonus, if you want to display how each feature from one image matches to another image, you can do the following:

```
%// Spawn a new figure and show the two images side by side
figure;
imagesc(cat(2, Ia, Ib));

%// Extract the (x,y) co-ordinates of each best matched feature
xa = fa(1,bestMatches(1,:));

%// CAUTION - Note that we offset the x co-ordinates of the
%// second image by the width of the first image, as the second
%// image is now beside the first image.
xb = fb(1,bestMatches(2,:)) + size(Ia,2);
ya = fa(2,bestMatches(1,:));
yb = fb(2,bestMatches(2,:));

%// Draw lines between each feature
hold on;
h = line([xa; xb], [ya; yb]);
set(h,'linewidth', 1, 'color', 'b');

%// Use VL_FEAT method to show the actual features
%// themselves on top of the lines
vl_plotframe(fa(:,bestMatches(1,:)));
fb2 = fb; %// Make a copy so we don't mutate the original
fb2(1,:) = fb2(1,:) + size(Ia,2); %// Remember to offset like we did before
vl_plotframe(fb2(:,bestMatches(2,:)));
axis image off; %// Take out the axes for better display
```

Comment: @Andr. Ludw, how can than that be a "great  answer" when you specifically asked about `dsift`, not `sift`. Could you add your code to the question to clarify that point.

Comment: @B... - `vl_sift` and `vl_dsift` by default compute equivalent features.  You just have to do a little bit of pre- and post-processing.  I chose to use `vl_sift` here so that the OP can visually see some stuff with minimal post-processing.  What I said about `sift` is essentially the same as `dsift`. See the example here: http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html . I'll put in a little note at the beginning of my post to make sure that this is assumed. Thanks for pointing out the difference, but there's no need to be condescending.

Comment: @Andr.Ludw. - You're very welcome.  I'm glad that this adequately answered your question.

Comment: @rayryeng  I think `vl_sift` and `vl_dsift` calculate the same features when the points are the same, but `vl_dsift` calculates them every `step` pixels whereas `vl_sift` only calculates them at key points. I was really perplexed about how `vl_dsift` could return differing numbers  of features for same size images. It now seems the question wasn't about dsift at all and I wasted my time thinking about it. But for plain sift, yours is a good answer.

Comment: @B... - I agree.  I believe that this question was independent on what kind of SIFT was being calculated.  The OP simply wanted to figure out why there is a differing amount of features detected per image, regardless of the method being used.